# Cordova get image uri after select from gallery

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to get the image uri after select an image form gallery, my current code only returns the encoded image data itself, how do I modify this to get the uri?

Thanks

```
        navigator.camera
                    .getPicture(
                            $scope.onFileSelectSuccess,
                            $scope.onFail,
                            {
                                quality : 50,
                                correctOrientation: true,
                                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                                destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                                sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                            });
```